# How to log only specific things to log file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, logging

I'm working on web scraping where I should **scrape** multiple URLs. I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to do the task.

I also want to implement logging in it. I want only specific debug or info or warning statements to be written to log files. But it is actually writing every request to log file.

How do I make that to write only specific statements that I mentioned with `logging.info` or `logging.warning` etc to the file.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='BOM.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.debug('Logger initiated')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    startt = time.time()
    futures = [executor.submit(get_movie_details, movie_id) for movie_id in all_movies_ids]
    for result in as_completed(futures):
        all_movies_summary_data.append(result)
    endt = time.time()
    print("Time Taken: {:.6f}s".format(endt - startt))
```

This is how the log file looks like:

```
2019-03-31 16:21:04,722 - DEBUG - Logger initiated
2019-03-31 16:21:04,731 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.boxofficemojo.com:443
2019-03-31 16:21:04,733 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): www.boxofficemojo.com:443
2019-03-31 16:21:04,736 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (3): www.boxofficemojo.com:443
.
.
.
```

How do I make sure that I get only the Logger initiated in log file and not the remaining. Why am I getting extra content in log file though I didn't explicitly mention it log those items anywhere.

Am I looking completely wrong at logging or something?

I tried setting the log level as suggested by **glhr** in one of the answers

But it's giving the output like this.

```
2019-03-31 17:07:29,817 - INFO - Logger initiated
2019-03-31 17:07:30,981 - WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.boxofficemojo.com
2019-03-31 17:07:30,994 - WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.boxofficemojo.com
2019-03-31 17:07:30,997 - WARNING - Connection pool is full, discarding connection: www.boxofficemojo.com
```

Comment: If you genuinely seek a solution which is portable between Python 2 and Python 3, please [edit] your question to elaborate on this requirement. If not, please remove at least one of the misleading tags.

Comment: Here is a working solution [link](https://gist.github.com/meta-ks/217ce41fc215e69a630db576bbbd23bc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig` configures the *root* logger from which other loggers inherit from.

As a result, the logging configuration set using this method will apply to logging made by other modules, hence the additional log lines in the log file.

In order to log only *your* messages:

(adapted from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial)

```py
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create file handler and set level to INFO
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('BOM.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# 'application code'
logger.debug('not shown in log file')
logger.info('info message in log file')
logger.warning('warning message in log file')
logger.error('error message in log file')
```

Result `BOM.log`

```
info message in log file
warning message in log file
error message in log file
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the logging level in `basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='BOM.log', format=...
logging.info('Logger initiated')
```

This will ignore logging messages less severe than `INFO`.

Comment: Messages can also be filtered by their source and contents as the modules you use also produce their own logging output.

Comment: Please see the updated content in question. I tried what you said. But getting different output. They are still being printed with `warning` level.